# Lotus Notes Agent - extract attachments from a Lotus Document to Domino Server File System

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, agent, lotus

I need to extract Attachments from a document to file system (/tmp/) of Domino Server.
Domino Server is on Aix 1.6.
Method I use :

```
Set ritem = ParmDoc.GetFirstItem("AttachedFiles")
If ( ritem.Type = RICHTEXT ) Then
    ForAll o In ritem.EmbeddedObjects
        Call o.ExtractFile  ( "/tmp/"  )
        Print "2222     
    End ForAll  
End if
```

Thrown error :

> Agent message: Lotus Notes Error Text= Notes error: Cannot write to a directory. (/tmp/)
> Lotus Notes Error Code= 4005

This happens even though Lotus Domino user has full permission on that folder.

Note : I can create file in the same directory using

```
strFname = pstrFullPath + "STAFILENAME"  
expfileNum = FreeFile()
Open strFname For Output As expFileNum
Print #expFileNum , strn
Close expFileNum
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You literally answer your own question...

> I can create file in same directory using...

You try to extract the file "as directory". Just add a filename and it will work as desired:

```
Call o.ExtractFile  ( "/tmp/" & o.Source  )
```

From the [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_EXTRACTFILE_METHOD.html) of "ExtractFile":

> Parameters
> path$
>
> String. The **path and file name** where you want to store the extracted file on disk.

Comment: Ok !!!! This is done ....